# Regexp remove duplicate whitespace leaving only 1 or 2 occurences

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making a simple comment box and I want to remove excess whitespace by replacing the whitespace with only 1 or 2 tokens, whether they be newlines or spaces.

`(\s){2,}` is what I have so far.
However, I want to leave users with the ability to double-space their comments, and replacing this with `$1`, the first capture group, would reduce their lines to a single space.

So basically,

If I have 1 space or newline,
then replace it with 1 space or newline.

If I have *more than* 1 spaces or newlines,
then replace it with **exactly** 2 spaces or newlines.

Thanks.

Comment: `(\s){2,}` does not match a single whitespace, so it is fine, just replace with `$1$1`. Or, use `(\s{2})\s+` with `$1` if you need to preserve the first two whitespaces.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you. Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
.replace(/(\s{2})\s+/g, '$1')
```

*Details*:

- `(\s{2})` - Group 1: two whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = 'Abc 123\n DEF 234\n      New line'
console.log(text.replace(/(\s{2})\s+/g, '$1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
text=document.getElemntById('comment_text_input').value
while(text.indexOf('\n\n\n')!=-1||text.indexOf('   ')!=-1) {
 text=text.replaceAll('\n\n\n','\n\n') //it makes '\n\n\n\n\n\n' to '\n\n\n\n', the next round '\n\n\n' and finally '\n\n'
 text=text.replaceAll('   ','  ') // the same with the newlines
  }
document.getElemntById('comment_text_input').value=text
```

Comment: While this is brilliant, I was trying to do it using regexp. I should've mentioned that. Thank you

Comment: Its make this simpler (you at first get the form data as formatted). And does not burden your server.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace matches of

```
(?<=\s)\s+/
```

with a space.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ijtcpo/1)

The regular expression reads, "Match one or more whitespace characters that are preceded by a whitespace character". `(?<=\s)` is a *positive lookbehind*.

Note that the characters below marked `'^'` are matched by the regular expression and then replaced by a single space:

```
Two spaces  then three   then four    then five\n    then none
           ^           ^^          ^^^           ^^^^
```

When matches are replaced by a space the string becomes the following.

```
Two spaces  then three  then four  then five\n then none
```

Notice that the space following the newline character is the first of four whitespace characters that are matched.